# Adding Teiid to JBDS

Tags: wildfly, jboss-developer-studio, teiid

I am trying to connect JBDS with wildfly server.
I am not getting  the Teiid instance  in JBDS.
What are the values for username and password in managment login credentials?
What are the values for username and password under JDBC connection.
Do I need to add anything in server for working.
Guides in Teiid Designer perspective is empty

Comment: Please provide the versions of the tools and servers you're using, and on which OS you're running them. That'll help us identify what you're doing and why it didn't work. Or, if you prefer, open a JIRA here: https://issues.jboss.org/secure/CreateIssue.jspa?pid=10020&issuetype=1

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **JBDS 11.0** as your base IDE then Teiid Designer will install but not be fully functional, which would explain the Guides View being empty.  We'll be releasing a compatible version in a couple of weeks which will work with JBDS 11.0.

If you are using **JBDS 10.x** then please log any issues here: https://issues.jboss.org/projects/TEIIDDES/summary

In the following document you'll find set-up instructions for creating credentials for ***Admin*** and ***Application*** users

- https://teiid.gitbooks.io/teiid-quickstarts/content/categories/prerequisites.html#_downloading_and_installing_teiid

The **Application** credentials are used when connecting to any deployed Teiid VDB artificat via their JDBC connection

- https://teiid.gitbooks.io/teiid-quickstarts/content/categories/Client.html